# import a python module from a user-specified dir?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have a cross-platform GUI interface to PyInstaller. I would like to check the version of PyInstaller that is installed. The user provides the install folder of PyInstaller. I can do this through the command-line `python pyinstaller --version` but that opens a command-prompt on Windows which I want to avoid. Is there a way to access the get_version() function in a Python module not in the same path as the application being run? Alternatively, how do I prevent the command-prompt from launching on Windows while maintaining cross-platform compatibility of my app.

Here's my code so far:

```
def pyversion(installdir):
    flags=[]
    flags.append(sys.executable)
    pylocation = os.path.join(installdir, 'pyinstaller.py')
    flags.append(pylocation)
    flags.append('--version')
    p = subprocess.Popen(flags, 
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out,err = p.communicate()
    return float(out.strip()[:3])
```

Comment: If the GUI is being run by the same python where `pyinstaller` is installed to then you could just `from Pyinstaller import get_version; version = get_version()`. Or modify `sys.path` to import from your directory assuming versions are compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_path = "some/path/blah"
os.path.insert(0,my_path)
import my_custom_module
```

you just need to add it to the path before importing it...or maybe I dont understand what you are asking

Comment: you might mean `sys.path.insert(0, my_path)` (and assert afterwards that the module is imported from that path (inspect `.__file__` or similar))

Comment: os.path.append doesn't exist. sys.path.insert worked! thank you.